# Get Product Entity Id on event catalog_product_import_finish_before magento 2

Tags: import, magento2

I need to get product entity id on product import. I am unable to get product entity id in my observer. Below is the code:

Events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="catalog_product_import_finish_before">
<observer name="generate_ipn" instance="Chetu\Generateipn\Observer\Productimportfinishbefore"/>
</event>
</config>
```

Observer file Productimportfinishbefore.php

```
<?php

namespace Chetu\Generateipn\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productimportfinishbefore implements ObserverInterface
{    
    protected $logger;
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $observer = $observer->getData();
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/mylogfile.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info($observer);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// Try with below code.

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 {
     $adapter = $observer->getEvent()->getAdapter();
     $Entityids = $adapter->getAffectedEntityIds();   
 }
```

Comment: We are not getting product object in this event catalog_product_import_finish_before.

Comment: $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_import_finish_before', ['adapter' => $this]);

Comment: This function getAffectedEntityIds() is in magento 1. I have tried this. We donot have this function in magento 2.

Comment: Please check this link . https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93975/get-product-from-save-event-observer-magento-2

Comment: controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after and catalog_product_save_after works on saving the product from admin panel. We want product id on product import and add our functionality.

Comment: Above events are not dispatched on product import.

Comment: controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after and catalog_product_save_after does not works on product import.

Comment: You can check in details code here.  File path : /vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php  Method Name : _importData